# zend 2 select from doctrine empty item not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper syntax for populating a zend framework 2 select element from a doctrine table.

```
            $form->add(
                array(
                    'name' => 'List',
                    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
                    'options' => array(
                        'label' => 'List',
                        'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
                        'target_class'   => 'Application\Entity\Lists',
                        'property'       => 'ListId',
                        'display_empty_item' => true,
                        'empty_item_label'   => '---',
                        'label_generator' => function ($targetEntity) {
                            return $targetEntity->getId() . ' - ' . $targetEntity->getListName();
                        },
                        'find_method' => array(
                            'name' => 'findAll',
                            'params' => array(
                                'orderBy' => array('ListId' => 'ASC'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            );
```

The problem I'm having is instead of displaying a '---' empty item, I'm getting 'NULL'

I've also tried adding 'empty_option' into there with the same result.

**EDIT:**

select result:

```
<select name="sublist">
    <option value="">NULL</option>
    <option value="1">OTHER STUFF</option>
    [..]
</select>
```

Comment: I even tried setting 'display empty item' to false - NULL still shows up at the top

Comment: why don't you use DQL createQuery [link] http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: rename `'property'       => 'ListId',` to `'property'       => 'ListName',` 
Also check out this tutorial:
https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/zend-framework-2-using-doctrinemoduleformelementobjectselect-and-custom-repository/

Comment: changing 'property' => 'ListName' still gets NULL for the first select

Comment: nevermind, found it with my edit. I noticed the 'name' was 'List' instead of 'sublist' *smacks self*

Comment: ok, this raises a new question. The field in question is a doctrine one-to-many relationship field, so apparently doctrine was already building a 'sublist' element when I use the AnnotationBuilder to create the form. Can I modify the empty element of that after the fact?

Comment: OK, figured that one out too: `$form->get('sublist')->setEmptyOption('---');`